# How can do improve this code for use OneHotEncoder?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

Hello I am using the following function to convert all categorical values in a dataset into a numerical, but I want to convert this to use OneHotEncoder, How can do it?

```
def categorical_to_numerical(dataframe):
    for col in dataframe.columns:
        if str(dataframe[col].dtype) == 'category':
            dataframe[col] = dataframe[col].astype("category").cat.codes
    return dataframe
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to use `DataFrame.select_dtypes`, to select the `object (string)` columns.

```
# example dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,3],
                   'col2':['a','b','a'],
                   'col3':[4,5,6],
                   'col4':['aaa', 'bbb', 'bbb']})

   col1 col2  col3 col4
0     1    a     4  aaa
1     2    b     5  bbb
2     3    a     6  bbb
```

```
for col in df.select_dtypes('object'):
    df[col] = df[col].astype('category').cat.codes

   col1  col2  col3  col4
0     1     0     4     0
1     2     1     5     1
2     3     0     6     1
```

Or if you want to actually `OneHotEncode`, we can use `pd.get_dummies`:

```
df = pd.get_dummies(df)

   col1  col3  col2_a  col2_b  col4_aaa  col4_bbb
0     1     4       1       0         1         0
1     2     5       0       1         0         1
2     3     6       1       0         0         1
```

Comment: I want to remplace cat.codes by OneHotEncoder

Comment: Please let me know if second solution is what you want, then it's a duplicate

Comment: The second option is the anwser thanks